# How to define a function in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, web, ionic-framework, ionic2

I cannot define a simple function in Ionic 2. This is my code:

```TS
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';  

@Component({
    selector: 'page-account',
    templateUrl: 'account.html'
})
export class AccountPage {

    function show() //←THIS FUNCTION
    {
        alert("show");
    }

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

}
```

then this is the error in the web browser:

[image: Ionic error]

I'm using ionic 2.2.0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to go through typescript a bit.. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `function`

Just make your code:

```
show() //Return type would be `show(): string` f.e.
{
    alert("show");
}
```

Comment: i'm new to this. can u explain why define functions without "function" keyword ?

Comment: The `show()` is a property of the `AccountPage` class it is in. So basically it already knows you are creating either a value property or a function property. Setting the `function` would be redundant this way

Answer (score 1):

Remove function from `function show()`

```
export class AccountPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }


    show() //←THIS FUNCTION
    {
        alert("show");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 2. You can directly start your the function from it's name itself without needing to declare "function" as prefix.

Similarly with ionic life cycle functions. You can see more on this function's declaration syntax in this link: http://www.ionichelper.com/2016/10/11/ionic-2-components-quick-guide-series-app/