# Firebase Dynamic Querying using results of barcode scanner (Ionic 3 & Angularfire2)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, barcode, angularfire2

I have a case where I need to ***dynamically*** retrieve the results of a ***specific*** book. I would like to retrieve that specific book by using its ***ISBN number*** (highlighted in bold below). This is how my database looks like:

```
{
  "results" : 
  {
    "key1" : {
      "Character_Depth" : 4,
      "Dialogue" : 4,
      "Plot" : 5,
      "Theme" : 3,
      "Writing_Style" : 3,
      "bookName" : "Ionic",
      "isbnNumber" : "0123456789012"
    },
    "key2" : {
      "Character_Depth" : 4,
      "Dialogue" : 4,
      "Plot" : 4,
      "Theme" : 2,
      "Writing_Style" : 4,
      "bookName" : "Justin",
      "isbnNumber" : "036000291452"
    }
  }
}
```

Before I dive into the code, here is some important information I think you need to know. What I am trying to specifically do is use a barcode scanner to scan the ISBN number of a book. Then I would like to use that scanned ISBN number to dynamically retrieve results from that database. With that being said, I need to design my code in such a way that the barcode scanner variable is updated every single time (with each scan) to the new barcode number (already completed). Then that barcode number is fed into the query (which I still can't get to work, and ***is what I need help with***) which retrieves a child node based on that number.

My code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  bookResults: Observable<any[]>;
  options: BarcodeScannerOptions;
  results: {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams, 
              private fire: AngularFireAuth, 
              private database: AngularFireDatabase, 
              private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, 
              private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

/* ########## part of the code where I specifically need help ########## */
        this.bookResults = this.database.list('results').valueChanges();
  }

/* ########### Barcode scanner function */
  async Scan(){
    this.results = await this.barcodeScanner.scan();
    console.log(this.results);
  }

}
```

Right now, what happens is that the `"this.bookResults = this.database.list('results').valueChanges();"` retrieves the above database. However, I need some guidance as to how to change my query such that I can retrieve specific child nodes based on the "isbnNumber" instance of each child.

I've tried several things. More recently I've tried:

```
 this.bookResults = this.database.list('/results', {
 query: {
    orderByChild: isbnNumber,
    equalTo: this.results,
    }
 });
```

but that didn't work. I've tried other things such as:

```
 this.bookResults = 
 this.database.list('/results/${this.results}').valueChanges();
```

but it hasn't worked either.

I've read various stackoverflow threads, so I wouldn't be surprised if this was marked as duplicate. I have tried following the instructions of various threads, yet I felt that the way retrieving information from the database didn't specifically apply to my current situation, as the values used to retrieve specific child nodes where hardcoded into the query. I need a dynamically changing query that adjusts itself based on the barcode scanner's results).

Please let me know if there is anything that was unclear from this post, and I'd be more than happy to help. Also, if you are interested in seeing the source code, here is a link to my github repo containing it:

https://github.com/islamaymansais/honey_scanner
(go to src -> pages -> login -> login.ts)

Thanks for taking the time to read this long post. I am a beginner , I've gone through plenty of posts but unfortunately I was not able to apply the appropriate changes due to my lack of experience with ionic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I tried your suggestion and the application crashed. This was the error it gave me: "cannot read property 'text' of undefined type error" So I updated code to: async Scan(){ this.results = await this.barcodeScanner.scan(); this.results = this.results['text'] } Then in your code I updated it to: this.bookResults = this.database.list('/results', ref => (typeof this.results != "undefined" && this.results != "") ? ref.orderByChild('isbnNumber').equalTo(this.results) : ref ).snapshotChanges();

Comment: However, I am not getting any results. I'm not sure if it is a problem with the query itself of my html is invalid. The terminal says "consol.warn: FIREBASE WARNING: Invalid query string segment:" In my HTML i use this to demonstrate the results: <ion-item *ngFor="let results of bookResults | async"> <h2>Book Name: {{results.bookName}}</h2> </ion-item>

Comment: Do you think it is a problem with the HTML? I've updated my git repository so that you can have a look at that specific page if you'd like to see the code fully and clearly Link to section of the repo: github.com/islamaymansais/honey_scanner/tree/master/src/pages/… I name this page as "login" but I should probably change the name to make it less confusing. However, this is page you'd be interested in.

Comment: I just tried rerunning my update and this is what I get:

Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'false'.

More specifically the error being highlighted is the ".equalTo(this.results)" component of the updated code:

this.bookResults = this.database.list('/results', 
    ref => (typeof this.results != "undefined" && this.results != "") ? ref.orderByChild('isbnNumber').equalTo(this.results) : ref
      ).snapshotChanges();

Please advise

Comment: `this.results.text` will contain the barcode scanned isbn Number of the book. You are saving the barcode scan result in the results object. You need to pass it to the query to get the specific firebase database objects. I shall edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: kindly check the edited post.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion here is what happened:
1) When I type "function" beside getData() I get the following error that is mentioned in this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308964/how-to-define-a-function-in-ionic-2 

2) I remove the term "function" from beside getData(): and error I get is:

Uncaught(in promis): ReferenceErrror: getData is not defined ReferenceError: getData is not defined at new LoginPage)

Please advise. Thank you so much again!

Comment: kindly try the update made.

Answer (score 0):

As per the readme notes for the Angular firebase library the following should work:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
          public navParams: NavParams, 
          private fire: AngularFireAuth, 
          private database: AngularFireDatabase, 
          private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, 
          private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
   this.getData();
}


async function Scan(){
   this.results = await this.barcodeScanner.scan();
   console.log(this.results);
   this.getData();
 }

this.getData = () => {
  var scanned_Barcode_Text = "";
  if (Object.keys(this.results).length > 0){
     if(typeof this.results['text'] != 'undefined' && this.results['text'] != ""){
      scanned_Barcode_Text = this.results['text'];
     }
   }


  this.bookResults = this.database.list('/results', 
        ref => (scanned_Barcode_Text != "") ? ref.orderByChild('isbnNumber').equalTo(scanned_Barcode_Text) : ref
  ).snapshotChanges();
}
```

call the `getData()` function in the constructor and also in the success function of the barcode scan.

The orderBy and equal to queries can only be called on the reference objects which is the second parameter(optional) of the AngularFireDatabase object. The usage is similar to the reduce function of the Array.prototype.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let booksRef = this.firebase.database().ref("results/");
booksRef.orderByChild("isbnNumber").equalTo(scannedBarCode).on("child_added", function(data) {
   console.log(data.val());
   this.bookResults = data.val();
});
```

I am considering that you have got the barcode value already and have it in the variable `scannerBarCode`.

Sidenote: In my opinion, since you are querying the database on ISBN, you should use that instead of `key`. It will make it simple. Also try the new Cloud Firestore that has better querying features.

Comment: Hi Samarth, thanks for getting back to me. I added your suggestion into my code but unfortunately it returned the following error:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined

I'm not sure if this is due to not importing the right libraries or making the right declarations in the constructor, or a completely different reason. Please advise me. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Also, does it make a difference if the suggested code block is added inside the constructor or the barcode scanning function? In both cases I got the same error.

Comment: The code provide is for javascript and not for typescript

Comment: Thanks for the update (yes it is TypeScript, sorry I forgot to mention that. Here is more information you might want to know. I'm working on Ionic 3, and using Firebase 5.6.0). I tried running the new update. It crashed and gave the following error: 

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.database is not a function
TypeError: this.database is not a function

Code updated on github incase you want to see live version: 

https://github.com/islamaymansais/honey_scanner/tree/master/src/pages/login

Please advice. Thanks alot